pymqi : IBM MQ ERROR : MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2381: FAILED: MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR
i have a problem on my script in Python.
I use the library pymqi for send message in IBM MQSeries.
But i have to use SSL and my script return an error !

Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\myDirectory\testMQ.py", line 92, in <module> connect_to_mq() File "c:\myDirectory\testMQ.py", line 68, in connect_to_mq qmgr.connect_with_options(queue_manager, cd, sco) File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pymqi_init_.py", line 1747, in connect_with_options raise MQMIError(rv[1], rv[2]) pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2381: FAILED: MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR

My environment :
OS : Windows 10
Python : 3.10.7
pip : 23.2.1
pymqi : 1.12.10
IBM MQ : 9.2.0.21

I have in my possession for an SSL connection, a truststore and keystore file with a password each.
And here is my code :
import pymqi

queue_manager = "<QUEUE_NAME>"
channel = b"<CHANNEL_NAME>"
host = "<HOST>"
port = "<PORT>"
queue_name = "<FILE_QUEUE_NAME.QA>"
user = b"<user>"
password = b"<pwd>"

conn_info = '%s(%s)' % (host, port)

ssl_cipher_spec = b"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
key_repo_location = b'C:/myDirectory/keystore.jks'

message = '{"message":"Hello from Python !"}'

# ------- GET MESSAGE -------
# Message Descriptor
md = pymqi.MD()
# Get Message Options
gmo = pymqi.GMO()
gmo.Options = pymqi.CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT | pymqi.CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
gmo.WaitInterval = 5000 # 5 seconds
# ------- GET MESSAGE -------

# ------- SSL INFO -------
cd = pymqi.CD()
cd.ChannelName = channel
cd.ConnectionName = conn_info.encode('utf-8')
cd.ChannelType = pymqi.CMQC.MQCHT_CLNTCONN
cd.TransportType = pymqi.CMQC.MQXPT_TCP
cd.SSLCipherSpec = ssl_cipher_spec
cd.UserIdentifier = user
cd.Password = password

sco = pymqi.SCO()
sco.KeyRepository = key_repo_location
# ------- SSL INFO -------

# qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info, user, password)
qmgr = pymqi.QueueManager(None)
qmgr.connect_with_options(queue_manager, cd, sco)

queue = pymqi.Queue(qmgr, queue_name)

# Envoi
print(f"Envoi du message")
queue.put(message)
print(f"Message envoyé")

queue.close()
print(f"Fermeture")
queue = pymqi.Queue(qmgr, queue_name)

# Lecture
print(f"Lecture du message")
msg = queue.get(None, md, gmo)
print(msg)

queue.close()
print(f"Fermeture")
qmgr.disconnect()
print(f"Déconnexion")

I followed the example here, but I think some parameters are missing for my case; like the trustore
And I don't see how to do it !
Help me please

You can't use a java key store with pymqi, convert it to a kdb with runmqckm.

ok, I have to convert only my keystore ?
The trustore is not useful ?

MQI clients like pymqi have just one key store,  it functions as both trust and keystore.

Does this answer your question? How to use Keystore to connect to SSL enabled IBM MQ using NodeJS

See the other answer I linked to,  it had the command to cover from jks to kdb.

If you need to also add the trust store certs you should be able to use this: runmqckm -cert -import -db truststore.jks -type jks -target target.kdb -target_type cms

Thanks @JoshMc for all this information

I'm having problems again. The conversion was more complicated than expected, I had the error "Invalid keystore format" and it took me longer than expected to resolve this problem, and not necessarily having a lot of time to devote to it. So I was finally able to convert it with the following command:
runmqckm -keydb -convert -db myKeyStore.jks -pw default -old_format jks -new_format cms
Which generated a kdb and rdb file for me.
So using this kdb file in my script, I always get the following error:
pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2381: FAILED: MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR

is it because of the kdb file password?
should we add in the script:
sco.KeyPassword = key_repo_password

So I also generated the stash file via the following command:
runmqckm -keydb -stashpw -db myKeyStore.kdb
I put this file in the same location as the kdb file, but I still get the same error

Try to validate the stash with this command note the 3rd from last is "a" not "c". runmqakm -cert -list  -db myKeyStore.kdb -stashed.  Also review your client AMQERR01.LOG to see if it provides more clues on the cause of the repository error.

The command was returned this (I hid some words with *) :
`5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2018.
Certificats d'tect's

par d'faut, - personnel, ! s'curis', # secret key
!       "ac racine **** ppd"
!       ac_infrastructure
!       ac_racine
!       "ac infrastructure **** ppd"



  client-********`




And in the logs :
AMQ9660E: SSL Key Repository; password storage file
missing or unusable.
EXPLANATION :
The SSL key repository cannot be used because MQ cannot obtain a
password to access it. The reasons likely to have given rise to this
error are as follows:

Please add the output to the question, it is unreadable in a comment. If i understand the runmqakm output indicates the stash file is fine,  if the error is related to the application,  I would suggest you check the sth ownership and permissions to ensure it is readable by the application.
